# Disable gpu when not using it?

Tags: windows, gpu

It's ok to disable the gpu when not playing games or using heavy programs?

Or this can cause something wrong with my gpu?

I want to disable when im just browsing the internet.

[image]

Comment: This is entirely pointless. Your GPU will of course still be active, albeit without specific drivers. It may even use more power because the generic driver knows nothing about power saving.

Comment: As long as your computers is ON the GPU is active.  If your BIOS has the option to turn off the built-in GPU, which I doubt, your whole screen will always be blank.  Even surfing the net requires the GPU!  Some servers are headless, and require remote desktop, but this doesn't apply to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea. Disabling your GPU drivers wouldn't disable your GPU, and if you did ***completely*** turn off your GPU, you wouldn't get any display output to your monitor.

Comment: Ok thanks for aware me. Thank god i didn't disable.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that most modern graphics hardware is also pretty good about energy efficiency when idle, so your GPU probably isn't using much power when idle.